# After mounting drive (NTFS) via fstab cannot change permissions to newly created directories

Tags: permissions, ntfs, fstab

I have Ubuntu server edition installed on server machine which is a part of Windows AD. To this server I connected external matrix via miniSas card. There is an NTFS partition which is visible as sde1.

I want to automount it so I used fstab to do this. Here is a line from fstab:

```
LABEL=lun01 /media/storage/lun01 ntfs defaults,umask=002,uid=1000,gid=10002 0 0
```

after mount it looks like this (`ll -a`):

```
drwxrwxr-x 1 user domain administrators 4096 Apr 13 12:04 lun01/
```

Everything looks fine here but on this partition I want to create a directory and change its permissions, for example:

```
cd /dev/sde1
mkdir office
chown 'user:office' office
```

After I do this nothing changes. Also when I try to change permissions with only `chmod 770` nothing happens. There is no error info but after `ll -a` I see that nothing was changed

```
drwxrwxr-x 1 user domain administrators 4096 Apr 13 12:04 lun01/
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want? Automount of partition with possibility to change permissions for directories and files stored on it.

Thanks for any reply!